# Accessing personal repos in Github after enabling 2-factor authentication broken

Tags: git, github

I am part of an organization on Github so I can see its private repos, plus i have some personal, public repos outside of it.

Now, I have enabled 2-factor authentication, generated the access code as per documentation and what happens is I can access (from terminal) the organization's repos but not mine anymore!

When trying to push I get indeed error

> remote: Permission to martinapugliese/DS-notebooks.git denied to
>   ***.

where *** is one of the members of the organization I am also part of.

Anyone can explain whether I should do two different access tokens/configure git somehow differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I enabled 2FA on Github, but I don't remember it changing anything about push privileges.

Github's 2FA controls access for logging into your account on the website (and to a certain extent, API authentication).  Pushing, however, is authenticated through the ssh keys attached to your account.

You can [test your ssh setup](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/) to see who Github thinks you are:

```
[$]> ssh -T git@github.com
Hi xiongchiamiov! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

This should return your user.  To double-check, you're using only one account for both your personal stuff and the organization?

The only other thing I can think of is that you might have your local clone configured to use https authentication to Github instead of ssh.  `git remote -v` will show the urls configured for your remotes; they should be `git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git`.  If not, grab the clone url from Github again and modify `.git/config` to use that instead of the https url.

Comment: I indeed solved by adding the username in front of github.com in the git/config file, so from github.com/username/repo.git to username@github.com/username/repo.git

Comment: Glad we found out the problem!